# Cannot update tracked property via did-update in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to use `did-update` in my template to trigger an action within my component from another component. I have done this before but never with an action that updated a tracked property.

I am trying to show a modal window whose display relies on the tracked property.

I have tried with another tracked property that is not called in another function in that component and I get the same error.

Is it at all possible to update a tracked property through this method?

```
// template
{{did-update this.triggerShare @showShareModal}}

// component
@tracked isShareOpen = false;
@action
triggerShare() {
  this.isShareOpen = !this.isShareOpen;
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
index.js:172 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to update `isShareOpen` on `ListingShareComponent`, but it had already been used previously in the same computation.  Attempting to update a value after using it in a computation can cause logical errors, infinite revalidation bugs, and performance issues, and is not supported.

`isShareOpen` was first used:

- While rendering:
  ----------------
    (instance of a `(unknown object)` modifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering the weird nugget of a gem Ember hat bestowed upon us, it thankfully has an easy workaround. I don't know why but ember doesn't like the toggle function where I set the property to the opposite value of itself.

I separated the toggle function into an open and close function, explicitly setting the values to either true or false and that works.

```
// template
{{did-update this.triggerShare @showShareModal}}

// component
@tracked isShareOpen = false;

@action
openShare() {
  this.isShareOpen = true;
}
@action
closeShare() {
  this.isShareOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: I would guess that `showShareModal` is flickering when passed into this component or something else is causing `did-update` to fire many times. Placing a `debugger` or `console.log('called'`) statement in the `triggerShare` action will show how many times it is being called and why Ember is giving you that performance error.